# How to rename a network interface on NixOS?

Tags: networking, network-interface, nixos

How to rename existing interfaces to a standardized names (i.e "internet0", "dmz0", etc).

The goal is to use the same names across different configuration.

Answer (score 5):

You can use udev rules to accomplish this. Just add something similar to your `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` and rebuild.

```
  services.udev.extraRules = ''
    KERNEL=="wlan*", ATTR{address}=="00:00:00:00:00:00", NAME="alfa_honeypot"
  '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Current NixOS versions have a dedicated setting for this particular task: `networking.usePredictableInterfaceNames = false;`. See [the documentation](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/#sec-rename-ifs) for more details.